# How do I hide a div on mobile

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, hide

I have the following landing page - [Cold Call with Confidence](http://www.coldcallwithconfidence.com)

There are two downward facing arrows on the page that are generated with the code below:

```
<div class="content" style="padding-top:0px;">
    <div class="right sld_cont">
        <img src="http://coldcallwithconfidence.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Arrow_comic_right_gray_T.png">
    </div>
    <div class="left sld_cont">
        <img src="http://coldcallwithconfidence.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Arrow_comic_right_gray_T1.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to hide one of the arrows on mobile as it looks repetitive in the mobile view.

Can anyone explain how I might do that?

Comment: This looks vaguely like a spam question...

Comment: The site has a half-baked landing page. It would be a pretty pathetic attempt at spam (which it's not).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you are looking to hide the right arrow on viewports that stack those elements rather than specifically hiding them on mobile devices.

The previous answer is correct based upon your question, however I think this might be a more suitable solution for you.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 679px) {
   .right.sld_cont {
   display: none;
   }
}
```

This means that for any viewport that is 679px or smaller the right arrow will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MobileDetect.js , then you can use this as a PHP if statement, and only show it if it's not a mobile device.

```
if(!$detect->isMobile()) {
    # desktop code
}
```

Edit:

```
<?php if(!$detect->isMobile()) { ?>
<div class="content" style="padding-top:0px;">
    <div class="right sld_cont">
    <img src="http://coldcallwithconfidence.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Arrow_comic_right_gray_T.png">
    </div>
    <div class="left sld_cont">
    <img src="http://coldcallwithconfidence.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Arrow_comic_right_gray_T1.png">
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is so outside my limited scope of knowledge. Do I add MobileDetect.js to the <head> and then use the if(!$detect->isMobile()) {
    # desktop code
} code in my HTML?

Comment: This will work in PHP. Google MobileDetect.js and you'll find the homepage. It's well documented. Have a go, then come back and update us if you need help!

Comment: I checked it out. I get adding this code - <script src="mobile-detect.js"></script> - to <head> but everything else is a complete mystery. My PHP knowledge is pretty much non-existent and my basic programming background is limited so it's tough for me to figure things out.

Comment: Okay, obviously you need to transfer the js file to your own workspace, and also declare the class just before (it's in the documentation). Then, change your html page to a PHP page and insert what I put in my answer, inside <?php and ?> tags, and replace #desktop code with the html code you initially put.

Comment: Here is my challenge. My theme, which is easy to use but not flexible, is built by "stacking" 6 widgets on top of each other to create a landing page. A widget can be just a block of HTML (as it in this case) but I don't believe it would accept PHP. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you search for and install plugins to use with this system then? There may be a mobile detection plugin you can use

Comment: Good idea. Let me try that.

Comment: I just tried it. There are plugins that will let you implement MobileDetect.js with a WordPress shortcode but it can't be used in this widget area since it isn't implemented with HTML. Frustrating.